# Node.js Express app with request module - Upload image to CouchDB using PUT

Tags: node.js, express, request, couchdb, image-uploading

I am using Mikeal's request module to talk to the CouchDB HTTP API from an Express app. I can't use any other modules (such as nano) as this an academic project.

What I would like to do is get an image file, that has been uploaded from a form in a web app, and save it to my Couch as an attachment. To do this using curl is very simple:

```
curl -vX PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/albums/6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af/artwork.jpg?rev=2-2739352689
--data-binary @artwork.jpg -H "Content-Type: image/jpg"
```

What I can't wrap my head around is how to structure the PUT request using the request module.  Express stores the file temporarily in the directory

```
/tmp/{doc._id}.jpg
```

How do I get the file from there to my couch? Pretty desperate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't verified this, but you might be able to do this:

```
var 
 fs = require('fs'),
 request = require('request'),
 url = 'http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984/albums/6e1295ed6c29495e54cc05947f18c8af/artwork.jpg?rev=2-2739352689';
var requestStream = request.put(url);

requestStream.on('response', function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
fs.createReadStream('image.jpg').pipe(requestStream);
```

Comment: I added the default couchdb credentials, just in case

Comment: If you stream it, the file saves, but you don't get a HTTP response from CouchDB, which I need as it contains the revision number for the document.

Comment: I've updated the code which should allow you to get the response back from CouchDB. Do you get an empty response from CouchDB?

Comment: That'll do. It works and you don't have to load the file into memory. Job done. Thanks.